# linq query depending on first column

Tags: sql, linq

my table data is like this,

```
col1 col2 col3
A  A1 1
B  B1 1
A  A2 1
B  B2 1
C  C1 1
D  D1 1
E  E1 1
A  A3 1
```

so I want data like this

```
A 3 3
B 2 2
C 1 1
D 1 1
E 1 1
```

how can i query in linq please

Comment: Could you plz add table schema?

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply i just want like A is having 3 entries b is having 2 entries like that and count of c for each A

Comment: Why is `c` lower case? The `A1`, `B1`, etc, mean nothing? The `1` at the end is redundant? And in the results why is the number repeated?

Comment: Could you provide your source data as valid c# code?

Comment: var details = tablelist.GetDetails(UID);
here i am getting the values like mentioned above( first )

Comment: Do you want  Linq or SQL answer?

Comment: @PR13R - Could you please answer my questions?

Comment: Just as a note it seems max is required from the second column (or the count of the A or B or ... of the second column). The logic must be explained first.

Comment: i want linq query
here A is having 3 entries each 3 entries having 3 values so how to query to get result shown in above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = db.MyData
             .GroupBy(x => x.Column1)
             .Select(x => new {
                Column1 = x.Key,
                Count = x.Count(),
                Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Column3)
             });
```

Here is a sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var myData = new[] {
        new {col1="A", col2="A1", col3=1},
        new {col1="B", col2="B1", col3=1},
        new {col1="A", col2="A2", col3=1},
        new {col1="B", col2="B2", col3=1},
        new {col1="C", col2="C1", col3=1},
        new {col1="D", col2="D1", col3=1},
        new {col1="E", col2="E1", col3=1},
        new {col1="A", col2="A3", col3=1}
        };

    var result = myData
             .GroupBy(x => x.col1)
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 Column1 = x.Key,
                 Count = x.Count(),
                 Sum = x.Sum(y => y.col3)
             });
    result.Dump(); // LinqPad
}
```

Output:

```
Column1,Count,Sum
A 3 3 
B 2 2 
C 1 1 
D 1 1 
E 1 1
```